# "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift

I'm working on a Swift project and I keep getting this error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" on this block of code:

```
func addPicture(pic: Picture!){
    pictureArray.append(pic)
}
```

(Note: I've tried it both as `pic: Picture` and `pic: Picture!` and I get the same error either way)

pictureArray is defined as such:

```
    var pictureArray: [Picture]!
```

I get this error when I'm trying to save the picture and pop the current VC:

```
@objc func dismissViewControllerAndSave() {
    let picture = Picture(name: "NewPic", preview: "newpic", colorDictionary: [:], blueprint: [])
    let viewController = ViewController()
    viewController.addPicture(pic: picture)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

I've been working on trying to fix this issue for a long time and I'm not sure how to resolve it. `picture` isn't an optional value so I have no clue why I keep getting this error. I'd really appreciate any type of help I could get. Thanks!

Comment: Change picture array like so `var pictureArray: [Picture] = [Picture]()`, as it is nil the first time you call this and with `!` you can't check for nils on it

Comment: I don't consider this an exact duplicate (and while I suspect there is one, I haven't found it so far), but you should also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `!` type is an implicitly unwrapped optional (IUO). It means that the value is technically Optional, but it is a programming error for it to be read if it is nil.

As a rule, you don't need IUOs. There are a few corner cases where they come up around initialization ordering, and they used to be necessary to deal with unannotated Objective-C bridging. But most of the time you don't need them, and you definitely don't need to pass a `Picture!` as a parameter (I can't think of any case where that would make sense).

Remove the `!`.

```
func addPicture(pic: Picture){
    pictureArray.append(pic)
}

var pictureArray: [Picture]
```

When you do that, you'll probably get an error that `pictureArray` isn't initialized. That's good. That error is telling you where you've made your mistake. You probably just want to initialize it when you define it in this case:

```
var pictureArray: [Picture] = []
```

You could also initialize it in `init`.

For more information on IUOs, see "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals" in the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330). For the common corner case where they actually are useful, see [Unowned References and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID55).